# Dynamic / variable routing in Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

Im trying to get Laravel to allow multiple routes to 1 controller. The reason for this is I want to use my code for multiple projects. Imagine the following:

```
// Routes to the products
Route::get('/products', 'ProductController@index');
Route::get('/products/{id}', 'ProductController@product');
Route::get('/products/{id}/{any}', 'ProductController@product');
```

and

```
// Routes to the products
Route::get('/items', 'ProductController@index');
Route::get('/item/{id}', 'ProductController@product');
Route::get('/item/{id}/{any}', 'ProductController@product');
```

This seems overkill to me - I tried creating a custom configuration file and adding the preferred uri's

```
// custom config
return array(
    'product_plural' => 'products',
    'product_single' => 'product'
)
```

and adding this to my routes

```
// Routes to the products
Route::get(Config::get('myconfig.product_plural'), 'ProductController@index');
Route::get(Config::get('myconfig.product_single').'/{id}', 'ProductController@product');
Route::get(Config::get('myconfig.product_single').'/{id}/{any}', 'ProductController@product');
```

This results into an

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
```

Which makes me believe that config is not available at routing. Clearly I am doing something wrong, I'm just a bit at a loss at the moment. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would be most grateful.

Comment: run `php artisan routes` to make sure you have routes you expect here and if you still have problem you should show when you get this error (which url you run).

Comment: Thank you @MarcinNabiałek - this showed me an error in my custom config file - and was able to fix this, now everything is working as I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have hit a route you haven't defined...

run `php artisan routes` and check if you have registered the url you hit as a route.

Comment: That is exactly what Marcin Nabiałek in November last year said, and was the correct answer. Thanks though.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't read the comments... Please ask Marcin to post it as an answer or just accept my answer, for future users . Else, it'll make it harder for them